# Compare position of a specfic item from an old to a new list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python on the same form as the following:

```
list = [["player1", "team1", "pointsPlayer1"],["player2", "team2", "pointsPlayer2"]]
```

The list contains between 0 and 20 players.

My problem is that I want to be able to know how many places each player gains or loses after new points are given (after a round). 
I know I'll have to make a copy of the list before points are given and then compare it to the updated list, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What's the expected output? A dict of `{player: gains}`? Also, are the points stored as numbers? Your example seems to indicate that the points are strings.

Comment: What does the data of each round look like?

Comment: The points are integers and each player can receive between 0 and 10 points after each round, depending on their finishing position.

A dict would be perfect as an output :)

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is an equivalent structure of `numpy` array which is basically a list of lists, and I'd suggest you using `numpy` array for this. I don't know what do you mean by gain but this is a little snippet that I quickly wrote to give you an idea. Does it work for you? (Assuming that the array is entirely of type `int`)

```
import numpy as np

players = np.zeros((20,3), dtype=int)

def get_gains(points): # also numpy array
    gains_dict = {}
    for i, point in enumerate(points):
        current_points = players[i][2]
        gain = current_points + point
        gains_dict[players[i][0]] = gain
        current_points = gain
    return gains_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` is a useful tool for this kind of task. It's not clear exactly what your inputs and desired output look like, but below is an example you should be able to adapt.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

# ROUND 1
c.update({'player1': 40, 'player2': 20, 'player3': 30})
# Counter({'player1': 40, 'player2': 40, 'player3': 60})

order1 = {k: idx for idx, (k, _) in enumerate(c.most_common())}
# {'player1': 0, 'player2': 2, 'player3': 1}

# ROUND 2
c.update({'player1': 10, 'player2': 40, 'player3': 15})
# Counter({'player1': 50, 'player2': 60, 'player3': 45})

order2 = {k: idx for idx, (k, _) in enumerate(c.most_common())}
# {'player1': 1, 'player2': 0, 'player3': 2}

# CHANGE IN ORDER
change = {k: order2[k] - order1[k] for k in c}
# {'player1': 1, 'player2': -2, 'player3': 1}
```